# Site for testing socks5 authentication

Tags: authentication, testing, github-actions, socks, dante

I need an online service for testing socks5 authentication so I can run automated tests on my code (in a GitHub Workflow Action). Locally I have set up a dante server for testing and will set one up in Workflow if need be. My preference is for an online service to lessen the infrastructure burden on anyone cloning/developing/testing my code.

Something analogous to https://httpbin.org/#/Auth but for socks would be ideal. Can anyone point me at a suitable service?